# Jetpack Compose app crashes w/ new version

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I updated my compose version from 1.1.1 to 1.4.2. Now, my app won't start with this error in the only activity:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getOnBackInvokedDispatcher()Landroid/window/OnBackInvokedDispatcher; in class Landroid/app/Activity; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.Activity' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

Update: For api versions > 33 it works as expected, how can i "re-support" lower versions ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: No, i went back to version 1.1.1 ...